# What is a way to prove, that holomorphic functions, when multiplied will give a result, that is also holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I just started learning complex calculus and was introduced to holomorphic functions. I was familiarized with the property that the multiples of two holomorphic functions will also be holomorphic. Yet it raised interest in me, how can this property be proven?

Comment: I think rather than "how can this property be proven to exist" you mean *how can this property be proven.*

Comment: Do you see how $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ iff for all $a\in U$, as $z\to a$ there is some $C$ such that $$f(z) = f(a)+C (z-a)+o(|z-a|)$$ this property behaves nicely for products, sums, powers, compositions, quotients (when $f(a)\ne 0$)...

Comment: How did you prove the product rule for derivatives in ordinary calculus? That proof, nearly word for word, applies to holomorphic functions.